# First use of \gls from glossaries doesn't produce a long version of acronyms with Latex Workshop

Tags: luatex, xindy, vscode, latex-workshop

I want to use the `glossaries` package to generate two glossaries with one acronym glossary. It worked well with TexStudio and MiKTex but if I try it with Latex Workshop in VS Code and Tex Live, the first use of `\gls` doesn't produce the expected output. It's always the short form. If I try to load the package with the option `acronym`, the long form occurs but the `\printglossary` doesn't work anymore.

I use a recipe with xindy to compile the glossaries and LuaLaTeX. Both were used before with TexStudio.

An Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[urlcolor=black,hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist,section=chapter,nomain,xindy]{glossaries}

\newglossary*{acronym}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis} %must be created first    
\newglossary*{symbol}{Symbolverzeichnis} %must be created second
    
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries 

\newacronym[type=acronym, longplural={Immissionsrichtwerte}]{acr:IRW}{IRW}{Immissionsrichtwert}
\newacronym[type=acronym]{acr:Abk}{Abk}{Abkürzung}

\begin{document}

\newpage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}\markboth{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}\printglossary[type=acronym]

\chapter{Test}
\label{ch:test}
Testtext mit den Glossaryeinträgen \gls{acr:IRW} und \gls{acr:Abk}. Eine Wiederholung der Einträge sieht so aus: \gls{acr:IRW} und \gls{acr:Abk}. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: By LaTeX workbench do you actually mean LaTeX Workshop? If not, could you please link to it

Comment: @JamesT yes, thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  The front end shouldn't matter.  If you put a `\listfiles` command before `\documentclass`, then toward the end of your log file will be the files that were loaded along with their versions.  Are there any differences in that list between what works and what doesn't?

Comment: @Teepeemm where do I find the log-file? Unfortunately, I don't have the earlier setup installed (It was on my old Laptop). I tried to recreate it with MiKTex and Perl, but the result is the same with short acronyms at first useage of \gls. glossaries was updated in 11/2022 and I used it before in 08/2022. Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: The log file is `filename.log`, and (by default) is located in the same directory as `filename.tex`.

Comment: I found a solution. The glossaries have to be created alphabetically for any reason. This is new to me, but I changed the creation order and the problem disappears. Thank you for your help!